# Joining attributes by field value not working

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, unique-id

I cannot figure out why this join is failing when using the [Join attribute be field value](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributestable) tool in QGIS 3.6.

Please see my image below which highlights the two layers attribute table and the criteria used in the tool:

[image]

I then get this error saying all features have failed to join:

[image]

**Some background**

1. The Autoincrimental layer had the PopID field created using the "Add autoincremental field" tool.
2. Both PopID fields are integers.
3. The PopID attribute values for the RF layer do not all have a value of zero. I have just ordered them from smallest to largest.

**Please see below for the datasets**

[Dropbox link for test data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uoinghvif8ceov1/AAA1ficxmPhjhOc_ShnJmluWa?dl=0)

Comment: PopID is all zeros in the 2nd file?

Comment: Sorry should have added that the window doesn't show all of them - there are in fact  more which match the numbers in the other layer. I have just ordered them.

Comment: PopID long(0,0) looks odd too

Comment: Maybe an issue with dealing with multipolygons and multipoints? Perhaps try converting to single polygons and points and try the tool again?

Comment: @IanTurton I agree that is strange - the Add autoincremental field does that. Still seems to work on other layers I have tried it on.

Comment: @Joseph I have just tried running it after your suggestion and I still get the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible you have empty spaces before numbers in PopID columns of RF table? Try ediding one of the rows with same id in both tables to make sure.  I'd also try to duplicate columns for id in each table using field calc to make sure they are the same. What you get doesnt seem like an error, fields just dont match for some reason.

Comment: @Mat I have checked and cannot see any spaces - please see my edit as I have added a link to some test data if anyone wants to have a closer look.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is PopID fields are not of the same type.

You can see in layer properties that PopID in Autoincrement layer is "real" and in RF "integer". [image]

Algorithm sees "integer" 1 differently than "real" 1 or "string" 1. So, You should convert one of the ID columns. You can do it in field calculator:

[image]

This will create new field that you should use to join.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this is really strange because the examples I used for the screenshot were saved in memory and when I saved them only then was one showing as a real data type. After looking into this it would appear that QGIS does not correctly show the data type in a memory layer until it is saved.

Comment: I did some tests joining with created incremented field. If you use memory layer it works, if you save it as geopackage it works. Saving it as shapefile it does not since it saves the field as real although it says in export dialog it should be exported as int8. Bug or something over my understanding.. Bottom line, save as geopackage instead of shape (which is not a bad idea in general) or join directly with memory layer.

Comment: We should also be careful with the length and precision values, as they can get in the way of successfully operating this tool.